switch between validation mode on surveyjs
in my current surveyjs form I validate the errors at the end just when the user clicks on the send button.
but for a particular need I want to add a question in the first page and this question must be mandatory and if the user does not answer this question he will not be able to move on to the next page.
I summarize:
Add a checkbox to accept the general conditions of use, if he does not check he will not be able to move on to the next page, so we validate before he navigates to the next part, but once he has checked the next ones page (33 in my case) will be validated at the end with onComplete, basically the first page will be with onChange validation and from the 2nd until the end will be in onComplete validation.
I work with react:
const surveyProps = {
    model: model,
    onComplete: onComplete,
    onUploadFiles: onUploadFiles,
    onClearFiles: onClearFiles,
    showProgressBar: "top",
    checkErrorsMode: "onComplete",
    showTOC: !isXlDown,
    completedHtml: t("questionnaire.completed_questionnaire_confirm.text"),
    completeText: t("button.send"),
  };

const surveyProps = {
    model: model,
    onComplete: onComplete,
    onUploadFiles: onUploadFiles,
    onClearFiles: onClearFiles,
    showProgressBar: "top",
    checkErrorsMode: "onComplete",
    showTOC: !isXlDown,
    completedHtml: t("questionnaire.completed_questionnaire_confirm.text"),
    completeText: t("button.send"),
  };


If you wish to prevent users from filling in a form if a particular field remains empty on the first page and validate the rest of the form on completion, enable a special Start survey page. Please refer to the following demo: Custom Question Renderer. You'll see the 'I agree with the disclaimer' checkbox on the first page; a user won't be able to proceed without ticking the box.
